# how do you display the <select> options beside the text for the <select> and not below?

Tags: html

How do I display the options for a  to appear beside the text for  and not below?

```
 <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option value="Select">Select One</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

These options will appear below the select sometimes and beside it at other times. How can I fix it so that the options appear beside it?

Comment: could you share a screenshot of the problem you're facing?

Comment: a screenshot of the problem plus css code would help greatly. or you can just create a codesandbox and share it

Comment: how do I add a screenshot?

Comment: https://snipboard.io/WBlO2I.jpg  I want to move the options from below the select to beside. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `style = "float:left"` inside every option value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work. Options still appearing below the select.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use flexbox with row.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
 <h4>Number of options</h4>
 <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option value="Select">Select One</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

This will ensure theyre in the same row only until the view supports it(i.e it isnt too small)